# Codeigniter 3 session doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am new in CI and I just started building login system, using codeigniter 3. My test project is based on live server. When I autoload session library in in autoload.php and put an encryption key in config.php it shows me an error in browser. The error is  "The requested URL could not be delivered".
When session library is of, everything works.I think it might be the configuration of apache web server, beacouse in the local server exactly the same project works with sessions.
session autoloading:
 I will appreciate any advice that might help to solve this issue and  to use sessions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: This is the controller:

Comment: pls add some code and php info screenshots if possible

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

 
 public function index()
 {
           $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
            $this->login();
            }
        
        public function login()
        {
         $this->load->view('login');   
        }
        
        
        public function members()
        {
            if($this->session->userdata(is_logged_in)){
             $this->load->view('members');   
            }else{

Comment: redirect('main/restricted');
            }
            
        }
        
        public function restricted()
        {
         $this->load->view('restricted');   
        }
        

                public function login_validation()
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email',
                    'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
            
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim');
            
            
            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data= array(
                    
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'is_logged_in' => 1

Comment: );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                        
                redirect('main/members');   
            }else{
                $this->load->view('login');
            }
            
            
        }
        
        public function validate_credentials()
        {
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            
            if ($this->model_users->can_log_in()) {

Comment: return true;
            }else{
                
                $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','Incorrect username/password');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        
        
        
}